# Flask logging across multiple modules

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have the following directory structure in Flask and I am trying to add logging to this system. My APIs are defined in `main.py` and `backend.py` provides some backend logic to the APIs.

```
├── README.md
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
├── module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── backend.py
```

My APIs are defined in `main.py` and logging related components in the file are as below:

```
from logging.config import dictConfig
import logging
from module import backend

log_level = "DEBUG"
LOGFILENAME = "flask.log"
dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {'default': {
        'format': '[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    }},
    'handlers': {'default': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'formatter': 'default',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'filename': LOGFILENAME,
                'maxBytes': 5000000,
                'backupCount': 10
            }},
    'root': {
        'level': log_level,
        'handlers': ['default']
    }
})

app = Flask(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    logger.debug("DEBUG: Inside the home function")
    logger.info("INFO: Inside the home function")
    backend.test()
    return "Welcome"
```

Logging works as expected in main.py. Depending on the `log_level`, logs get written to `LOGFILENAME`.

Problems occur when I try to enable logging via the below steps inside of backend.py.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test():
    logger.info("info test")
    logger.debug("debug test")
```

I do not see any logs from `backend.py` getting written to `flask.log`. I sense I am missing something but do not understand what. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do you run `backend.py`?

Comment: `backend.py` is run by the APIs on `main.py` as
`from module import backend`
`backend.test()`

Comment: have you tried calling backend.test from the hello method?

Comment: Yes, sorry in trying to simplify the issue, I did not reflect this step above. Still no logs from `backend.py`

Answer (score 4):

Your library does have a different logger name. For both you need to have the same logger name. See for example [the logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-logging-in-multiple-modules).

The best practice is that you create your own logging hierarchy, for example "myapp" in main.py (`logger = logging.getLogger("myapp")`) and attach to this in backend.py with for example `myapp.backend` (`logger = logging.getLogger(".".join("myapp", __name__))`.

Find below a slightly modified version of your main.py and backend.py. I have removed the Flask part. I guess this does not affect the logging mechanics.

#### main.py

```
import logging.config

from module import backend

dict_config = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {'default': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'formatter': 'default',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': "test.log",
        'maxBytes': 5000000,
        'backupCount': 10
    },
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'formatter': 'default',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ["default"],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ["console"],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}

print(__name__)
logger = logging.getLogger("myapp")
logging.config.dictConfig(dict_config)


def hello():
    logger.debug("DEBUG: Inside the home function")
    logger.info("INFO: Inside the home function")
    backend.test()
    return "Welcome"


print(hello())
```

#### backend.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("myapp")

def test():
    logger.info("info test")
    logger.debug("debug test")
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. The moment I change to `logger = logging.getLogger("myapp")` on `main.py`, I dont see the logs from the API. Earlier when I used `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, I was able to view this.

Comment: sorry about that. Give me a minute, I'll check that out.

Comment: I think your logging dict is missing the `loggers` key, see https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#an-example-dictionary-based-configuration. All loggers not listed there get disabled. So you will have to put your logger name, the desired handlers and log level into the `loggers` section

Comment: Adding the loggers does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the fix to my problem. Given below is my updated `main.py` and `backend.py` and is comfirmed working

**main.py**

```
import logging
from module import backend

log_level = "DEBUG"
LOGFILENAME = "flask.log"
class LoggerConfig:
    dictConfig = {
        'version': 1,
        'formatters': {'default': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        }},
        'handlers': {'default': {
                    'level': 'DEBUG',
                    'formatter': 'default',
                    'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                    'filename': LOGFILENAME,
                    'maxBytes': 5000000,
                    'backupCount': 10
                }},
        'root': {
            'level': log_level,
            'handlers': ['default']
        },
    }

app = Flask(__name__)

logging.config.dictConfig(LoggerConfig.dictConfig)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    app.logger.debug("DEBUG: Inside the home function")
    app.logger.info("INFO: Inside the home function")
    backend.test()
    return "Welcome"
```

**backend.py**

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()

def test():
    logger.info("info test")
    logger.debug("debug test")
```

If you notice, the second line of `backend.py` is basically `logging.getLogger()` without a name. This did the trick on the `backend side`.

Also, `app.logger` on the API side (`main.py` side) helped.

Overall, I was able to get both the `main.py` and `backend.py` to write to the same file given in `dictConfig`.